# C# Appending Linq Queries of Same Type

Tags: c#, linq

I have two linq queries that I run on two different tables, Car and Truck.  From these queries I select the ID, Name, and Company.

```
var car = from c in db.Cars
          select new {ID = c.ID, Name = c.Name, Company = c.Company};

var truck = from t in db.Trucks
          select new {ID = t.ID, Name = t.Name, Company = t.Company};
```

How do I append the truck data to the car data using Linq so that the resultant query contains both car and truck data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the resulting types are equivalent, you can use [Enumerable.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) to combine them.

However, I wouldn't normally recommend doing this with anonymous types - instead I'd recommend making a custom class to hold your three (or more) properties.  It's possible, given the code above, that the type may be the same post-compilation, but it's impossible to tell for sure without more information.

Personally, I would either use a shared interface (ie: have `Car` and `Truck` implement `ICompanyInfo` with those properties in the interface), and return the car cast into the interface, or make a custom class, and return that from both queries, then use Concat to join them.

Comment: As long as the anonymous type has the same number of properties, of the same name and type, in the same order, then they are fine to use `Concat` on. The compiler will warn you if the property types don't match.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Yes - hence I said that it would likely work.  However, having multiple conditions like that leads to brittle software that's not as nice for long term maintenance.  I would not recommend anonymous types for something like this - it's obviously an important concept in the OP's software.

Comment: It's not a great design, at the moment, I'm simply just trying to create a brain dead simple way to populate a dropdownlist on this temp form.  In the future, car and truck will implement an IVehicle interface.  I don't really know the best way to setup an interface on datatables in a linq query, but I'll cross that bridge when I get to it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the `Union` operator, if they were the same type.  This should also work with anonymous types that have the same members:

```
var vehicles = from c in db.Cars          
    select new {ID = c.ID, Name = c.Name, Company = c.Company};
vehicles.Union(from t in db.Trucks          
    select new {ID = t.ID, Name = t.Name, Company = t.Company};
```

presuming that the id, name and company types are the same in both car and truck.

Comment: Union assumes that the OP does not want duplicates, which is probably a safe assumption in this case